# Unrelenting TemplateSyntaxErrors

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2

**Update #7**:

I removed the first line and put in its place the second line below which I copied from the jinja2 link [jinja2 install docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/intro/#installation).
But I still get the error below.

```
# from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from jinja2 import Template

  File "/Users/brian/googleapps/YouPoll/views.py", line 271, in get
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
NameError: global name 'template' is not defined
INFO     2012-07-08 22:43:53,053 dev_appserver.py:2952] "GET /?ID=testBSchott HTTP/1.1" 500
```

This appengine worked just a little while ago with the non-django code in the template files.

Furthermore, if I execute the following code in the gae Interactive Console, it works, even though it contains the {%- if ... -%} code that I think is unique to jinja2, not django.

```
from jinja2 import Template
template = Template('{%- if True -%}Hello {{ name }}!{% endif %}')
print template.render(name='John Doe')
```

**Update #6**:

Ok, I found the variable template being defined. It's below.

```
jinja_environment.filters['datetimeformat'] = datetimeformat

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def jinja2(self):
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

    def render_template(
        self,
        filename,
        template_values,
        **template_args
        ):
        template = jinja_environment.get_template(filename)
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
```

**Update #5:**

Here are my imports in views.py:

```
import jinja2
import os
import webapp2
import logging
import datetime
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.api import images
# from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader

from models import QA, PQ

TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_environment = \
    jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(TEMPLATE_DIR))
```

My use of template_values is below in some code I posted.
2 of the imports mention webapp, not webapp2. But if I change the first one to webapp2 I get this error.

```
  File "/Users/brian/googleapps/YouPoll/views.py", line 9, in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext.webapp2 import template
ImportError: No module named webapp2
INFO     2012-07-08 18:44:18,972 dev_appserver.py:2952] "GET /?ID=testBSchott HTTP/1.1" 500
```

And if I remove that line the the I get this error.

```
  File "/Users/brian/googleapps/YouPoll/views.py", line 272, in get
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
NameError: global name 'template' is not defined
INFO     2012-07-08 18:30:52,733 dev_appserver.py:2952] "GET /?ID=testBSchott HTTP/1.1" 500
```

Do you see anything I can do? Did I give the info you need?

**Update #3**:
If I remove these 5 jinja2 sequences/phrases
the html form works fine. But there is no syntax 
error with these 5 sequences/phrases. They used 
to work fine. And I have added below in my first
update the Traceback which includes django, although 
I am not using django -- only jinja. So what other 
error am I making?

I have also included at the bottom my html page prior
to removing the sequences/phrases above.

1

```
{% for choice in p.choices -%}
{% if not loop.first %}
,{% endif %}
 {% if loop.last %}
   &nbsp;or&nbsp;
 {% endif %}
 {{ choice }} 
{%- endfor %}.
```

2
    {% for choice in p.choices %}
    {% if not loop.first %}
    ,{% endif %}
     {% if loop.last %}
        or 
     {% endif %}
     {{ choice }} 
    {% endfor %}.

3

```
{{ q.answers|sum() }}
```

4

```
q.date|datetimeformat('%d-%m-%Y')
```

5

q.modified|datetimeformat('%d-%m-%Y')

**End of update #3**

This phrase which occurs before the errors, works fine.

```
   {% if p.purpose %}
   </p>
  <p> The purpose of this questionnaire is {{ p.purpose }}.
  </p>
   {% endif %}
```

But then this next phrase throws an error (apparently).

```
{% for choice in p.choices -%}
{% if not loop.first %}
,{% endif %}
 {% if loop.last %}
   &nbsp;or&nbsp;
 {% endif %}
 {{ choice }} 
{%- endfor %}.
```

Next is the error.

**Update #2**:
If I revise the "errant" 'for' statement, removing the space control '-'s, the system still moves on to the next error below, and yet the '-'s are not really errors.

```
ERROR    2012-07-06 21:46:07,107 webapp2.py:1553] 'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for choice in p.choices -
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

**Update #1**:

```
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/brian/googleapps/YouPoll/views.py", line 272, in get
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 89, in render
    t = _load_internal_django(template_path, debug)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 163, in _load_internal_django
    template = django.template.loader.get_template(file_name)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader.py", line 160, in get_template
    template = get_template_from_string(template, origin, template_name)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader.py", line 168, in get_template_from_string
    return Template(source, origin, name)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 158, in __init__
    self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 186, in compile_string
    return parser.parse()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 281, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 195, in do_extends
    nodelist = parser.parse()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 281, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 173, in do_block
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endblock', 'endblock %s' % block_name))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/__init__.py", line 281, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 684, in do_for
    " 'for x in y': %s" % token.contents)

TemplateSyntaxError: 'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for choice in p.choices -
INFO     2012-07-06 21:46:07,117 dev_appserver.py:2952] "GET /?ID=testBSchott HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

And if I remove that phrase from my template then this one throws an error (after skipping over some other (%ifs and {%fors ).

```
{% for q in qs|sort(attribute='seqnum') %}
```

Next is the error.

```
ERROR    2012-07-06 21:48:38,177 webapp2.py:1553] Invalid filter: 'sort'
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid filter: 'sort'
INFO     2012-07-06 21:44:03,051 dev_appserver.py:2952] "GET /?ID=testBSchott HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

And if I remove that phrase from my template then this one throws an error (after skipping over some other (%ifs and {%fors ).

```
<td align="right"> {{ q.answers|sum() }} </td>
```

And if I remove that phrase from my template then this one throws an error, too.

```
ERROR    2012-07-06 21:36:07,650 webapp2.py:1553] Invalid filter: 'sum'
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid filter: 'sum'
```

Etc. This looks like a signal that something else is wrong. But I don't have a clue. 
This template worked just a little before, but has stopped working, so I suspect there is some error in my python code that is the cause but I cannot imagine where to start looking.

Btw, the Traceback mentions Django often, when I am using jinja2, but I suppose that is irrelevant.

Below is the python code that I use to feed the template.
I have left in the logging info to show some of the debugging I have done.

```
qs = db.Query(QA)
qs.ancestor(person)
qs.filter('deleteRequested =', False)
qs.run()
for item in qs:
    logging.info("2 seqnum %d" % item.seqnum)
for item in person.choices:
    logging.info("2 choice %s" % item )
logging.info("2 title %s" % person.title  )
logging.info("2 person.key()%s" % person.key())

# template_values = {'ID_id':person.key(), 
template_values = { 'p': person,
    'qs': qs
    }
path = os.path.join(TEMPLATE_DIR, 'table.html')
logging.info("Here After Revise" )
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

**Update #4**:

Following is a listing of my html page which is failing.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<center>
    <h1>Make your preferences for <span class="emph">{{p.ID|escape}}</span> known here</h1>
   {% if p.title %}
  </center>
  <p><h2> The title of this questionnaire is: {{ p.title }}.</h2> </p>
  </center>
   {% endif %} 
  <br />

   <div id="inputdata">
   {% if p.purpose %}
  <p> The purpose of this questionnaire is: {{ p.purpose }}.
  </p>
   {% endif %} 
  <p>This is a participative preferences survey: you not only answer questions, you supply questions for all to answer.
  </p>
  <ol>
<li>
  To answer existing questions, click on the "Radio" button in the corresponding rows of the table: 
{% for choice in p.choices -%}
{% if not loop.first %}
,{% endif %}
 {% if loop.last %}
   &nbsp;or&nbsp;
 {% endif %}
 {{ choice }} 
{%- endfor %}.  
</li>
<li>
  After answering questions, at the bottom of the page click the "Submit" button to register you answers.
</li>
</ol>
  </div>
<br />
   <div id="inputdata">
  <p>To supply a new question or statement, click <a href="/add_question?ID={{ p.ID }}"><span class="emph">here</span></a>. At the present time there is no automated mechanism for editing or erasing an existing question.
  </p>
<br />
  <p>The question numbers (No's) are used to arrange the questions.  You place your question in the list with the number you choose.
  </p>
  </div>
   {% if not p.moreinfo == 'None' %}
   <p> {{ p.moreinfo }} 
   </p>
   {% endif %} 
<form action="table" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="{{p.ID|escape}}"></input><br/>
  <table border="1" cellpadding="2" 
      cellspacing="0" class="sortable" id="unique-id">
 <thead> <tr> 
<td>No</td>
<td>Question</td>
<td> Total </td>
{% for choice in p.choices %}
<td bgcolor="#fef886"> {{ choice }} </td>
{% endfor %}
<td> Created </td>
<td> Last answered </td>
</tr></thead>

<tbody>
    {% if qs %}
{% for q in qs|sort(attribute='seqnum') %}
    <tr>
    <td align="right"> {{ q.seqnum }} </td>
    <td> {{ q.question }} </td>
    <td align="right"> {{ q.answers|sum() }} </td>
    {# <td> {{ q.total }} </td> #}
        {% for answer in q.answers %}
    <td bgcolor="#fef886"> 
        <input type="radio" name="{{q.seqnum}}" value="{{loop.index}}"
        />
        {{ answer }} 
    </td>
        {% endfor %}
<td>{{ q.date|datetimeformat('%d-%m-%Y') }}</td>
<td>{{ q.modified|datetimeformat('%d-%m-%Y')}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</tbody>
</table>
  <br />
   <div id="inputdata">
       <p>To remember your own choices, print this page before ReLoading</p>
  </div>
<center>
  <input type="submit" 
   name="Submit" 
   value="Submit" /> 
  </center>
  </form>   

<script src="/static/javascript/sorttable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: If your traceback mentions Django, you're probably doing something wrong. Of course, the tracebacks you've posted don't mention django at all.

Comment: I have added in my template an if clause `"{% if qs %}"` to keep the template table from calculating when the `template_values = { 'p': person, 'qs': qs }` has no qs component. If that were the problem would my if clause circumvent the problem? It does not appear so, because I still get the same error. What else could be causing these errors? Are there other tests you can recommend?

Comment: @wooble  Can you look again at my question now that I have added updates, please? I have not found the error and am stumped.

Comment: You're not using jinja2, you're using Django templates. jinja2 syntax won't work. You don't show where the variable `template` is being defined, but it looks like you're somehow importing both webapp2 and webapp, and using webapp's django templating.

Comment: @wooble Where *is* the variable template defined? I have added more info as update #5. Thanks for looking.

Comment: `from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template`. Get rid of that, and use jinja2's template rendering.

Comment: You probably also don't want `run_wsgi_app` if you're using the Python 2.7 runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wooble really answered this question by commenting to get rid of from `google.appengine.ext.webapp import template` and replace it with `from jinja2 import Template`, but I had another error too which may have caused the original problem. I used `self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))` instead of `self.render_template('table.html',  template_values )` at one point.

The key problem was that gae was using django when I thought I was using jinja2 and Wooble keyed on that fact which I only mentioned casually in my original question.

(So I hope Wooble gets credit for this answer.)

Comment: Copilot brought me here.

I wasn't even doing anything with python or jinja or whatever. Instead of completing code, it printed a link to this answer. Interesting times.